# How to define a key value pair with values having a max size in c++

Tags: c++, data-structures

I would like to make a dictionary (may be similar to `std::multimap`) with several values for the same key. The main thing here is that I want the values to have a maximum size(n) and if an (n+1)th value comes, then the 1st value should be removed (like `boost::circular_buffer` or something). More specifically,

I have a struct

```cpp
Struct A{
   double id;  //  key
   double x, y, z;  // value
}
```

Then I define

```cpp
std::vector<A> a{}; 

while (condition)
{
    a = getFromSomeWhere();
   ////////////
   //  I DONT KNOW HOW TO STORE THE VALUES in `a` //
   //  THIS IS WHAT I AM LOOKING FOR //
   ////////////
}
```

When calling `getFromSomeWhere`, assume `a` gets the following values before the condition becomes false

```
{
a1, a2, a3, a4 
a1, a3, a4, a5
a2, a4, a6
}
```

The answer I am looking for should be something like

```
{ a1.id : a1, a1      // can go to a maximum size of n before removing the 1st 
  a2.id : a2, a2      // can go to a maximum size of n before removing the 1st
  a3.id : a3, a3      // can go to a maximum size of n before removing the 1st
  a4.id : a4, a4, a4  // can go to a maximum size of n before removing the 1st
  a5.id : a5          // can go to a maximum size of n before removing the 1st
  a6.id : a6          // can go to a maximum size of n before removing the 1st
}
```

Comment: So you don't want a maximum value for each key, you want a maximum _number_ of values with the same key. Can't you just use `std::map<Key, boost::circular_buffer<Val>>`? Is there something specific wrong with that?

Comment: I was thinking `std::map<Key, std::array<Val, MAX>>)` but yeah, a `std::multimap` is a little overkill when `std::map` will suffice.

Comment: You could always make a map of circular buffers, if that’s what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I am still unclear about setting the max size of the circular_buffer if I use `std::map<Key, boost::circular_buffer<Val>>`. For example, if I need to store the latest 100 values in the circ_buffer, how would the code look like?
Also, if I use `std::map`, then the value for the same key will be overwritten each time  a new value comes in the while loop, rt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the replies. I got it solved with help from [fCaponetto](https://github.com/fcaponetto).

```
#include<iostream>
#include <boost/circular_buffer.hpp>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

struct Vis
{
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
    
    bool seen;
    uint id;
};


typedef boost::circular_buffer<Vis> VisBuffer;
typedef std::shared_ptr<VisBuffer> VisBufferPtr;

void makeVisMap(const std::vector<Vis> &b, std::map<uint, VisBufferPtr> &visMap)
{
    unsigned int const max = 500;
    for (const auto &v : b)
    {
        if (!visMap[v.id])
            visMap[v.id] = std::make_shared<VisBuffer>(max);
        visMap[v.id]->push_back(v);
    }
}


int main ()
{
    Vis s1{}, s2{}, s3{}, s4{}, s5{};
    s1.id = 1; s2.id = 2; s3.id = 3; s4.id = 4; s5.id = 5;
    s1.x = s1.y = s1.z = 1;   s2.x = s2.y = s2.z = 2;   s3.x = s3.y = s3.z = 3;   s4.x = s4.y = s4.z = 4;   s5.x = s5.y = s5.z = 5;

    std::vector<Vis> sv {s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s2, s3, s4, s4, s4, s4};
    std::map<uint, VisBufferPtr> visMap{};

    makeVisMap(sv, visMap);

    return 0;

}
```